# Can't hide or disable the close button on QWizard

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

A QWizard dialog by default has a context help `[?]` and a close `[X]` button in the top right corner. I can hide the context help button, but I can't get the close button to disappear using `setWindowFlags`. For example:

```
# preserves current window flags but removes context help button
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowContextHelpButtonHint)

# has no effect
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```

Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `CustomizeWindowHint` flag needs to be set before the `WindowCloseButtonHint` flag can be changed. The full code is:

```
# enable custom window hint
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() | QtCore.Qt.CustomizeWindowHint)

# disable (but not hide) close button
self.setWindowFlags(self.windowFlags() & ~QtCore.Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
```