# How remove close button from QMessageBox PySide2

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, messagebox, pyside2

[image]

1. How I can remove close button from QMessageBox?
2. How I can increase Title text?

```
class ErrorModal(QMessageBox):
    def __init__(self, parent: Optional[None] = None):
        super().__init__(parent=parent)
        self.findChild(QDialogButtonBox).setCenterButtons(True)
        font = self.font()
        font.setPointSize(20)
        self.setFont(font)
        self.setStyleSheet('QLabel{color:white;}')

        self.setStandardButtons(QMessageBox.Ok)
        self.setIcon(QMessageBox.Critical)
        self.setPalette(ErrorPalette())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't hide or disable the close button on QWizard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496686/cant-hide-or-disable-the-close-button-on-qwizard)

Comment: Note that removing the close button might not work on all platforms, you might prefer overriding `closeEvent()` and ignore the event to prevent closing. The title font is not set by Qt, it depends on the system. If you want to customize it you will need to create your own title bar.

Comment: That answer didn't help me. But you gave me an idea, thanks!